# Need help getting JSON data from MYSQL database to Android App

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, parsing

I'm developing an Android app that connects to a remote MYSQL database and retrieves info via JSON data.  The part of the app I'm having trouble with involves searching by `userID` in the app, and returning the associated user info from the database, such as the ID, first name, company and position.

The problem is parsing the JSON data within the app.  The error message I get is `System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for id`.

The php page displays JSON data.  Two JSON objects are outputted: a `success` object and a `result` object.  The `success` object is properly parsed by the app and tells the app what to do via an if-statement.  So `if success == 1`, the app executes a block of code that should parses the `result` object and assigns each element of the array to a `String` value in the app. The output from the php page is:

```
{"success":1,"message":"UserID found!"}{"result":[{"id":"1100011","firstname":"Kevin","company":"company","position":"bartender"}]}
```

The problem is the values from the `results` object are not being parsed by the app.  Here is the php page:

```
 <?php
define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','********');
define('PASS','**********');
define('DB','**********');

if (!empty($_POST)){

if (empty($_POST['userID'])){
    $response["success"] = 0; 
    $response["message"] = "Please enter a User ID";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

$userID = mysql_escape_string($_POST['userID']); 

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $userID";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    array_push($result, array(
            'id'=>$row[0],
            'firstname'=>$row[4],
            'company'=>$row[6], 
            'position'=>$row[7], 
        )   
    );
}

if($result){
    $response["success"] = 1; 
    $response["message"] = "UserID found!";
    echo json_encode($response); // if I comment out this line, the result array gets parsed properly by the app.
    echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

}else{
    $response["success"] = 0; 
    $response["message"] = "UserID not found. Please try again.";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

mysqli_close($con);


} else {
?>
        <h1>Search by User ID:</h1> 
        <form action="searchbyuserid.php" method="post"> 
            Enter the UserID of the receipient:<br /> 
            <input type="text" name="userID" placeholder="User ID" /> 
            <br /><br /> 
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
        </form> 
        <a href="register.php">Register</a>
    <?php
}

?>
```

If I comment out the line noted above, the Log from the app shows the correct data being parsed by the app for the `results` array:

`D/UserID Lookup:: {"result":[{"id":"1100011","firstname":"Kevin","company":"company","position":"bartender"}]}`, but then I get an error for `W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for success` because `success` isn't being sent (obviously).

Here's my android code:

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog; ... 

public class SearchByUserID extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    // Buttons
    private Button mSubmitButton, mBackButton;

    // EditText Field
    EditText enterUserID;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // Variable for holding URL:
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://www.***********/webservice/searchbyuserid.php";

    //JSON element ids from response of php script:
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
    private static final String TAG_USERID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_FIRSTNAME = "firstname";
    private static final String TAG_COMPANY = "company";
    private static final String TAG_POSITION = "POSITION";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_by_user_id_layout);

        mSubmitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
        mBackButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back);

        mSubmitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mBackButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        enterUserID = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enterUserIdNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.submit:
                new SearchUserId().execute();
                break;
            case R.id.back:
                finish();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    class SearchUserId extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        // Show progress dialog
        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SearchByUserID.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Searching User ID...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            String userID = enterUserID.getText().toString();
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userID", userID));

                Log.d("UserID:", userID);
                Log.d("request!", "starting");

                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("UserID Lookup:", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    JSONObject json2 = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);
                    String userid = json2.getString(TAG_USERID);
                    String firstName = json2.getString(TAG_FIRSTNAME);
                    String company = json2.getString(TAG_COMPANY);
                    String position = json2.getString(TAG_POSITION);

                    Log.d("User ID Found!", json.toString());
                    Log.d("userid:", userid);
                    Log.d("firstName:", firstName);
                    Log.d("company:", company);
                    Log.d("position:", position);

                    Intent i = new Intent(SearchByUserID.this, HomeActivity.class);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                    Log.d("User ID not found.", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }
        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null){
                Toast.makeText(SearchByUserID.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

So basically I'm able to properly parse either the `success` object or the `results` object, but not both.  If I try to parse both, I get a JSON error for `no value for id`.

Comment: That is not valid JSON. You're outputting two JSONObjects. Just add the array to the response, and make sure you only call `echo json_encode()` once.  The result would look like this: http://pastebin.com/4QxBvyZF    As an alternative, you could also wrap it in a JSONArray with two JSONObjects, the result would like this: http://pastebin.com/0JHQYGqh

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: It's also bad form to jam in `die` calls in the middle of your code. If you have errors, set the response code, render something, and then do the usual cleanup.

Comment: For proper JSON format, check this: http://www.json.org/

Comment: @DanielNugent, thank you.  How would I revise the php code to format the array as you have indicated?  I've tried several ways, but none of them work.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject json2 = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);
JSONArray jsArray = json2.getJSONArray("result");

String usrid     = jsArray.getJSONObject("id");
String firstName = jsArray.getJSONObject("firstname");
String company   = jsArray.getJSONObject("company");
String position  = jsArray.getJSONObject("position");
```

try converting your code to this.